# IIS Architecture similar to Azure Application Gateway

Tags: azure, iis, proxy, reverse-proxy

I need to create a proxy on IIS that redirects "virtually" the user to a service. This must not be a reverse proxy because I must maintain request structure, URL of response and body request on POST.
We are using a similar approach in Azure with the Azure Application Gateway service, from that we protect the applciation while the request data remains immutated. Instead, with reverse proxy, response IP is from the target machine and we cannot perform other requests than GET

how can we achieve that in an IIS server?

Comment: "Instead, with reverse proxy, response IP is from the target machine and we cannot perform other requests than GET" is totally wrong, so you should go back and fix your reverse proxy rules, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: In IIS, in addition to reverse proxy, only [url rewrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) can be redirected, does this meet your needs?